# repeatedly click hidden button using selenium

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, css-selectors

I have several listings on a web page like the samples below.  The first listing displays an “Apply Now” button that I am able to click with the code below.  Then after I fill a dialog box and close it the first listing disappears from the page and the other listings are still visible.  However the “Apply Now” button doesn’t appear on the next listing until I click anywhere on the next listing, then the “Apply Now” button will pop up for the listing.  Also if I refresh the page the “Apply Now” button will pop up for the next listing.  If I try running the code below the second time, (when the “Apply Now” button isn’t visible for the next listing), I will get the error below.  My goal is to be able to click “Apply Now” for each listing, one after the next.  Can anyone suggest how to get the “Apply Now” button to appear for the next listing, in this example the “SecondOne”.  I’ve tried  the code below, but neither attempt works repeatedly.

1st listing:

```
<div data-id="972688" data-name="FirstOne" data-force-note="0" data-force-note-on-archive="0" data-allowed-to-mark-interest="1" data-listing-ids="[256855]" data-in-network="false" data-promoted="false" class="djl87 thing_listings fbw9 browse_startups_table_row _a _jm expanded" data-_tn="thing_listings/browse_startups_table_row" _js-initialized="true">
<div class="js-action-bar-placeholder action-bar-placeholder u-hidden"></div>\n<div class="action-bar browse_startup_action_bar" style="display: block;">\n<table>\n<tbody><tr>\n<td class="top-left-corner">\n<div class="star">\n<span>☆</span>\n</div>\n</td>\n<td class="right-corner">\n<div class="prompt">\n<div class="s-vgBottom0_5 u-hidden u-fontSize12 u-fontWeight400 u-textAlignLeft js-action-bar-details">\n<div class="action-bar-pic s-vgRight0_5 u-inlineBlock">\n<img alt="" src="https://d1qb2nb5cznatu.cloudfront.net/startups/i/972688-67bea67278d8a1b824cf5df5fa8dc1ae-thumb_jpg.jpg?buster=1522805890" />\n</div>\nWant to talk to FirstOne?\n</div>\n<div class="buttons">\n<a class="g-button blue apply-now-button">\nApply Now\n</a>
```

2nd listing:

```
<div data-id="1126380" data-name="SecondOne" data-force-note="0" data-force-note-on-archive="0" data-allowed-to-mark-interest="1" data-listing-ids="[451322]" data-in-network="false" data-promoted="true" data-promotion-event-id="20694189" data-verify-promotion-event-url="https://placeweb.co/thing_ads/impressions/20694189/verify" data-click-promotion-event-url="https://placeweb.co/thing_ads/impressions/20694189/click" class=" djl87 thing_listings fbw9 browse_startups_table_row _a _jm" data-_tn="thing_listings/browse_startups_table_row" _js-initialized="true">
<div class="js-action-bar-placeholder action-bar-placeholder u-hidden"></div>\n<div class="action-bar browse_startup_action_bar">\n<table>\n<tbody><tr>\n<td class="top-left-corner">\n<div class="star">\n<span>☆</span>\n</div>\n</td>\n<td class="right-corner">\n<div class="prompt">\n<div class="s-vgBottom0_5 u-hidden u-fontSize12 u-fontWeight400 u-textAlignLeft js-action-bar-details">\n<div class="action-bar-pic s-vgRight0_5 u-inlineBlock">\n<img alt="" src="https://d1qb2nb5cznatu.cloudfront.net/startups/i/1126380-9ca4e0e38d777ea699f703fe7db28cfb-thumb_jpg.jpg?buster=1537381145" />\n</div>\nWant to talk to SecondOne?\n</div>\n<div class="buttons">\n<a class="g-button blue apply-now-button">\nApply Now\n</a>
```

code:

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "button.g-button.blue.apply-now-button"))).click()


# clicks first "Apply Now" button

# driver.find_element_by_css_selector('.g-button.blue.apply-now-button').click()

# time.sleep(3)
```

Error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TimeoutException                          Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-46-792b206b8d3d> in <module>()
      3 from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
      4 
----> 5 WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "button.g-button.blue.apply-now-button"))).click()
      6 
      7 

~/anaconda/envs/py36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/support/wait.py in until(self, method, message)
     78             if time.time() > end_time:
     79                 break
---> 80         raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)
     81 
     82     def until_not(self, method, message=''):

TimeoutException: Message:
```

Comment: Seems the main issue is in the step _the “Apply Now” button doesn’t appear on the next listing until I click anywhere on the next listing_. Can you update the question with what exactly you do as in `click anywhere on`? on which element?

Answer (score 0):

Please try the following options to click on the element.

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//a[text()[contains(.,'Apply Now')]]"))).click()
```

OR

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "a.g-button"))).click()
```

If in case above two options not throwing any error and you still unable to click then try `JavaScripts` executor.

```
element=WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//a[text()[contains(.,'Apply Now')]]")))
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", element)
```

Let me know if this works.

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me.  Unfortunately none of your three suggestions worked.  If I navigate away to another url and then navigate back the new 'Apply Now' button appears.  So that's the hack I'm using for now.